# Django - Cannot update model with model form gives str error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Im trying to let the user update some of the settings on their team but it doesn't seem to work correctly I want to update the name and if they accept users.

## Views.py

```
@login_required
def teamsettings_general(request, team_pk):
    logged_in_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
    requested_team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=team_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for member in requested_team.teammembership_set.all().order_by('-leader'):
            if member.user.pk == request.user.pk and member.leader:
                form = TeamSettings_GeneralForm(request.POST, instance=team_pk)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    messages.success(request, "The team has been updated!")
                    return redirect('teamsettings_general', team_pk=team_pk)
    for member in requested_team.teammembership_set.all().order_by('-leader'):
        if member.user.pk == request.user.pk and member.leader:
            feedback = FeedbackSupportForm()
            form = TeamSettings_GeneralForm(instance=team_pk)
            context = {
                'requested_team': requested_team,
                'feedback': feedback,
                'form' : form,
                'logged_in_user': logged_in_user,
            }
            return render(request, 'team/settings.html', context)
            break
        else: return redirect('team', team_pk)
```

## and my form.py

```
class TeamSettings_GeneralForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'accepts_applications',)
```

Now I just want it to update name and accepts_applications

```
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

    form = TeamSettings_GeneralForm(request.POST, instance=team_pk)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "The team has been updated!")
        return redirect('teamsettings_general', team_pk=team_pk)
logged_in_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
requested_team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=team_pk)
form = TeamSettings_GeneralForm(instance=team_pk) ...
for member in requested_team.teammembership_set.all().order_by('-leader'):
    if member.user.pk == request.user.pk and member.leader:
        feedback = FeedbackSupportForm()
        context = {
            'requested_team': requested_team,
            'feedback': feedback,
```

Thanks in adbanvce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the Team instance, but then ignored it and passed the PK to the form instead. It should be:

```
form = TeamSettings_GeneralForm(instance=requested_team)
```